# Wallpaper background for gnu nano

Tags: desktop-background, nano, 20.04

So I have seen multiple text editors using some fancy background photos in the internet.

Is that possible with nano in ubuntu and if so how ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nano is a console editor. It is designed to work on text consoles. So it is unlikely that you can set a background in nano.

It is possible that some terminal emulators, where you run nano, could set an image background. The standard terminal emulator used in Ubuntu does not allow that.

What you might have seen, though, is the use of a transparent background. In Terminal, you can set the background (partly or fully) transparent. Click the "hamburger" menu, select "Preferences" and click your default "Unnamed" profile (or create a new profile). On the "Colors" tab, uncheck the option "Use transparency from system theme". Now you can check the option "Use transparent background" and set the level of transparency using the slider.